# DateTime.ParseExact fails

Tags: c#, datetime

The following lines throws a FormatException.

```
DateTime dateResult;
System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string dateFormat =  "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm";
string dateToCheck = "2013-20-10 00:00";

dateResult = DateTime.ParseExact(dateToCheck, dateFormat, provider); // fails
```

It says

> The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar
>   System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

I can't see what's wrong.

Comment: You have your day and month mixed up. There is no 20 month.

Comment: Are you trying to parse 20 as a month?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Month seems to be 20. There is no 20th month. As the comments suggests you might have mixed up day and month.

The string should be:

```
string dateToCheck = "2013-10-20 00:00";
```

Comment: Thank you. I suspected it was something like that.

Answer (score 1):

In your date format swap month and day, also its better if you use single `M` and `d` for Month and day respectively since it will account for both single and double digits month/day. *(You can also do that for Hour (single `H`))* Use the format:

```
string dateFormat =  "yyyy-d-M HH:mm";
```

This will handle days like : `02,2,20`

Answer (score 0):

Change your format from

```
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"
```

to

```
"yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm"
```

because there is no 20.ht month.

```
string dateFormat = "yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm";
string dateToCheck = "2013-20-10 00:00";
DateTime dateResult = DateTime.ParseExact(dateToCheck, dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
Console.WriteLine(dateResult);
```

Here a <kbd>[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/basc9W)</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 20th month in the calendar. Modify your code as:

```
...
string dateToCheck = "2013-10-20 00:00";
...
```

Or this:

```
...
string dateFormat =  "yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm";
...
```

Answer (score 0):

do it like this, Note i have swapped dd and MM

```
DateTime dateResult;
System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
string dateFormat = "yyyy-dd-MM HH:mm";
string dateToCheck = "2013-20-10 00:00";
dateResult = DateTime.ParseExact(dateToCheck, dateFormat, provider);
```